# changing global variables

Tags: c++, global-variables

I am facing a problem with global variables in c++. i have a function named `iDraw()`. and I planned to write two segments of code here which will be controlled by a `global variable` named `flag`. in the main function if i set `flag` to 1 and then call `iDraw`, then one portion of code will be executed; and if i set flag to 2 and then call it, then the other portion of code will be executed. but it isn't working expectantly.seems like when i am changing the value of flag in main function, it isn't working. It still holds the value which i declare in the top of program initially. what's the solution of overcoming it?
 i used a header file named `global.h` where i declared all the global vars.

```
extern int flag=0, animflag=1;
/* 
    function iDraw() is called again and again by the system.
*/
void iDraw()
{
    //place your drawing codes here 
    if(flag==1){
        iClear();
        iSetcolor(0,0,128);
        iShowBMP(0,0, "Images\\intro.bmp");
    }
    if(flag==2){
        //other codes here
    }
}
int main()
{
iInitialize(900, 500, "demooo");
animflag=0;
flag=1; // seems like this line has no impact
iDraw();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you stepped throught the code with debugger?

Comment: From the code you have posted that should work. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It should work. R u modifying flag anywhere else?

Comment: is this the real code or an example? I wouldn't be surprised if you have `int flag` somewhere inside the `main`

Comment: I should mention that using a global flag like this seems like a recipe for unexpected behavior: Sometime it will change out from under you unexpectedly causing undesired functionality.

Comment: it isn't the real code. the program is a bigger one. but i don't think  the problem is anywhere else. i have rechecked it. i myself is confused about the problem.

Comment: Then I still bet on `int flag` either in `main` or `iDraw` functions (as you don't mention other threads being executed, which obviously could affect the global flag, but you would mention that, wouldn't you?)

Comment: besides, almost all examples I see on SO where code should work but doesn't, boil down to the sample which differs form the actual code but the real cause was lost during 'simplification'. If you are not able to see the cause of the problem in real code, you will surely also miss it when rewriting it into simpler example.

Comment: In any case, debugging will almost surely show you the cause, just step through the code. You can also set breakpoints on variable modification, so you will see exactly what changes it.

Answer (score 2):

> i used a header file named global.h where i declared all the global vars.

If your program contains more then one .cpp file which includes this global.h there is the problem. Because each of this .cpp files have its own copies of the `flag` variable and changing one of them will not change another copies.

You must define global variables in one of the .cpp file. In global.h you may provide `extern` declarations.

```
//*.cpp
int flag = 0;

//global.h
extern int flag;
```